# Irregular date to regural date pattern

Tags: sql

how could i make the date pattern at regular interval like weekly or difference between the dates with 7 day and containing the valuu aslo.

```
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   30-Jun-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.59
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   07-Jul-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.49
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   21-Jul-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.44
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   04-Aug-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.13
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   25-Aug-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.69
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   01-Sep-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.01
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   08-Sep-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   1.98
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   22-Sep-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   1.88
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   13-Oct-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   1.91
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   20-Oct-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   1.93
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   27-Oct-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   1.96
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   01-Dec-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.08
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   15-Dec-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.21
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   22-Dec-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.24
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   29-Dec-75   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.29
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   05-Jan-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.34
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   19-Jan-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.36
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   02-Feb-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.44
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   09-Feb-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.52
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   16-Feb-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.54
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   23-Feb-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.59
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   01-Mar-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.62
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   08-Mar-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.64
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   15-Mar-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.69
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   05-Apr-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.74
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   19-Apr-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.82
Sylhet  SY072   Balaganj    GT9108001   26-Apr-76   0.46    9.85    24.68   91.80   2.85
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please post the code you have tried, along with what is going wrong so we can try to help

Comment: I didnt try any code yet .bec i am a new user .I just want to convert this data set with regular date interval .for example the interval betwenn two daters is 7.every dates will be separed by 7 days and containing the value.

Comment: I want yous help.other wise in canbe converted from into monthly avarage.suppose in january i have 3 dates .i just convert it into avagrage in only for january.

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase your question? the description is very short. show us the output you are expecting...

Comment: I just want to make the data  arrange in a regular pattern .all the date have the sma distance like weekly.other wise i want to convet the data into monthly avarare.just convert the data into monthly pattern.Suppose in january i have 4 separate dates,i just want to get the monly avagare data for every year.

Comment: My data is fron 1975 to 2011.Can i convert it only monthly data.suppose in januar  i want just the value of monthly value for the month january,feb,.....dec for every year.

Comment: Stn_Name Year JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV
Sylhet 1956 10 0 2 229 907 977 872 
 i want like this pattern only.please any one help me.it is emergency for me.